# Read a file in Matlab and access it in Verilog

Tags: matlab, verilog, system-verilog

I am trying to read a text file in Matlab and convert it into bits. I then want to access and store them in a register in my module in Verilog. I then use these bits inside the module. Can I do this? If yes, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to read a text file into Verilog and strore numeric values into a variable.  The easiest way is to use the `$readmemb` system task and store the values into a `reg` array.

Another way which is a little more work, but is also more flexible, is to use the `$fopen` system task.  Refer to the IEEE Verilog Std (1800-2009, for example).